# Fail to find 'pyperclip' in command line while run well in idle

Tags: python, module, python-import

I am learning python on my own by reading a textbook "automate the boring stuff". The book is easy to read. However, I still feel it is a tough job to start from 0 basement. I create a file with code shown below:

```
#! python3
#  py.exe mcb.py save [keyword] -save current context in clipboard
#  py.exe mcb.py list -list all keys saved before
#  py.exe mcb.py [keyword] -paste the value related with the keyword to clipboard


import sys, pyperclip, shelve

mcbfile = shelve.open('multiclipboard')

if len(sys.argv)==3 and sys.argv[1]=='save':
    mcbfile[sys.argv[2]]=pyperclip.paste()
elif len(sys.argv)==2:
    if sys.argv[1]=='list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbfile.keys())))
    else:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbfile[sys.argv[1]])
mcbfile.close()
```

The pyperclip version is 1.5.27. I believe that I only download once and use version 3.6.

I put the whole python software under disk I. So python.exe is just under I:. The file, named mcb.py, (the code shown above) is under I:\workdir. I have added python.exe into environment variables.

I can successfully import pyperclip in IDLE. I opened CMD, changed the direction to I:\workdir, and imported the code "python.exe mcb.py save a". This code would import pyperclip. The system suggested "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip' "   While if I typed again in the direction I:\, no error showed(I move mcb.py to the direction I:).

If changing my direction is the only way to solve my problem, I need to save my py files under disk I, which is not a good way for my to view my py files.

Comment: Sounds like a path problem. What happens if you `import pyperclip` in the python console (run python.exe)? You could try to check the install with `pip`. Try running your script with python.exe instead of py.exe, maybe there is another python version that you don't know of (as part of another program). Also, you could reduce your code to`import pyperclip`.

Comment: thanks for reply. I tries to type " import pyperclip" in python console, situation is as same as that in command line. I also tried to use python.exe instead of py.exe, still does not work. If there is another version of python, how I can know about that? Do I need to reinstall my python? Thanks!

Comment: `where python.exe` and `pip install pyperclip`

Comment: I found a strange thing. When I run python.exe in command line, at I:\, the code, "python.exe mcb.py save something" can work. While if I go into python at I:\workdir ( This is a folder under I:) in command line, the system fail to run the code.

Comment: Have a look at how to quote arguments in CMD. It may be unclear which argument is directed at which program (your script or python.exe, which also accepts arguments). But if you want help with solving this, you should get into the habit of [providing all information you can](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. system, exact command line, error message. You can edit your question to extend it with this information, nicely formatted.